# Attachment Server for uploading files, images using JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, upload, primefaces, image-uploading

I  have a different Http server(ServerB) planned for uploading the files, but figuring out what i need to  run and how i should program it to make it available for my main web application(Server A) to upload and download files. So that in case if we move to cluster environment, we can still point the same attachment server for uploading images/files etc And we are not burndening the main server if we are uploading plently of files each hour. So Server B is dedicated for upload and downloading attachment via ServerA. Our main application is build mostly on primefaces and JSF. I believe if we are using plain html, in the form we can define the "action" argument to different server, how to do the same in JSF. As of now we don't want to use third party CDN, we want to find alternate solution where we can host ourself in a seperate server. Any suggestion  or point me to the url where i can get more information.

Comment: You have a Web Application Server (server A) and a File Server (server B). Now, you want to upload/download files to/from server B using server A web app? If that's so, then you should find a way to get the data file from B and use it in A, maybe using Web Services or an ftp transaction, whatever suits better for your scenario.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Server A should'nt be handling the file upload and download as server B is dedicated to it.

Comment: As far as I can see, you want to have a pageX in your server A that will make a request to server B to upload the file, right? I don't really know if this can be achieved using JSF (at least I haven't tried it), but I had a similar problem in a JSF application, so we solved this by receiving the file binary data in our JSF app and send it to server B using a Web Service (the file never was physically on our JSF app).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my question is more related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972675/how-to-build-an-image-web-server . I am doing research on NginX to see whether it suits our requirement