# use nginX upload module in jsf for uploading images/files?

Tags: jsf, nginx, primefaces

Our webapplication is mostly built on primefaces, JSF. We would like to integrate naginx upload module for uploading images or any attachment. We want to run Nginx server in seperate box so it wil be as content server(for uploading and download files) for any of our web application server to use. If i use JSF forms () in the xhtml, what i suppose to mention to direct the request to nginx server instead our main server.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                .....  />
```

What i need to change in web.xml? Does this work this way?

Comment: Why didn't you edit [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465775/attachment-server-for-uploading-files-images-using-jsf)?

Comment: @siebz0r this is specific to Nginx and the previous one is for more general case.